# How to find single value with out _id in Mongodb?

Tags: mongodb

I have created one table. example

use abc

```
db.test.create( {rollid: 4451, Name : "MongoDb"}, {rollid: 4452, Name : "casandra"})
```

Now i need only one filed value without id.

I tried with the below query but id also displayed.

```
db.test.find({},{Name : "Mongodb"})
```

Here i received the output

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5bec88847825b85d854cd6e3"), "Name" : "MongoDb" }
```

But i don't need combination of "_id" and Name. I need only Mongodb name.

How can i  retrieve only one filed value without id?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
db.test.find({}, { _id: 0 }).toArray()
```

OR

```
db.test.find({}, { _id: 0 }).toArray(function(err, array) {
  // Do something with array
  console.log(array);
})
```

Comment: i got the solution. Thanks for the response.   db.test.find({},{"Name" : "MongoDb", "_id" : 0})

Answer (score 0):

See: See: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/#find-projection

```
db.test.find({Name: "MongoDb"}, {_id: 0})
```

Comment: i got the solution. Thanks for the response. db.test.find({},{"Name" : "MongoDb", "_id" : 0})